# Scanning a number having more data than predefined value

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

        unsigned int num;
        printf("enter the number:\n");
        scanf("%u",&num);//4294967299 if i'm scanning more than 4G its not scanning
        printf("after scanning num=%u\n",num);// 4294967295 why its giving same 4G

        /*      unsigned char ch;
                printf("enter the character:\n");
                scanf("%d",&ch);// if i/p=257 so its follow circulation
                printf("after scanning ch=%d\n",ch);// 1 its okk why not in int ..
         */
}
```

Why is circulation not following while scanning input via `scanf()`, why is it following in case of `char`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  But here they are `unsigned type` so why it will be unspecified behaviour .

Comment: at compile time if i'm taking more than range , value its giving correctly but why not at run time ?

Comment: Entering an integer literal that the compiler will parse is one thing, the `scanf` function is a completely other thing. Those two and their parsing is not related.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

From [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for the `"%u"` format:

> The format of the number is the same as expected by `strtoul()` with the value `​0​` for the base argument (base is determined by the first characters parsed)

Then we go to the [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) function, and read about the returned value:

> Integer value corresponding to the contents of str on success. If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, range error occurs and `ULONG_MAX` or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned. If no conversion can be performed, `​0`​ is returned.

From this we can see that if you enter a too large value for the `scanf` `"%u"` format, then the result will be `ULONG_MAX` converted to `unsigned int`. ***However*** the result will differ on systems where `sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(unsigned int)`. See below for information about that.

---

It should be noted that on platforms with 64-bit `unsigned long` and 32-bit `unsigned int`, a value that is valid in the range of `unsigned long` will not be converted to  e.g. `UINT_MAX`, instead it will be converted using modulo arithmetic [as detailed here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions).

Lets take the value like `4294967299`. It is to big to fit in a 32-bit `unsigned int`, but fits very well in a 64-bit `unsigned long`. Therefore the call to `strtoul` will not return `ULONG_MAX`, but the value `4294967299`. Using the standard conversion rules (linked to above), this will result in an `unsigned int` value of `3`.

Comment: ["If this object does not have an appropriate type, or **if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.**"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10) (emphasis added). `%u` expects the same **format** as a [subject sequence](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4p3) of `strtoul` with base 10, but the subject sequence is just that: format. It does not guarantee anything about the value, at least to my reading of the standard. Please feel free to correct my reading as necessary.

Comment: @SurajJain Because conversions from a large integer type to a smaller integer type is performed using modulo arithmetic. If, for example, `unsigned long` is 64 bits and `unsigned int` is 32 bits, the result is what is expected. [Read more about integer conversions here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Not really, it just follows the standard integer conversion rules. The problem with large number as shown in the comment by Suraj Jain is when `sizeof(unsigned long) > sizeof(unsigned it)`. The conversion is correct.

Comment: @IljaEverilä And that's why I have updated the answer to include 64-bit `unsigned long` being converted to 32-bit `unsigned int`. The answer was perfectly fine for both types being 32 bits, and now it includes information about what happens if they are not.

Comment: Why include bits at all. There's no need, except for the basic "your system may have an `unsigned int` of 32 bits and thus...". The answer is still both wrong and convoluted. It mixes behaviour of `strtoul` with `scanf("%u", ...)` that does not apply. Only the format of the subject sequence with base 10 applies.

Comment: One thing to note from the standard that it uses `strtoul` as the "formatting" example for `u`; even when we know that a conversion specifier `ll` flags, i.e. `%llu` cannot be necessarily presented by `strtoul`.

Comment: Maybe your answer is wrong please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162536/what-happens-if-i-input-number-more-than-the-range-of-data-type-in-c

Answer (score 6):

The C11 standard draft n1570 7.21.6.2 says the following

[paragraph 10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10)

> [...] the input item [...] is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure. Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the **behavior is undefined**.

Now, the word "conversion" here is used for string => result data type conversion, it cannot be understood to mean *integer conversions*. As the string `"4294967299"` converted to a decimal integer is not representable in an object of type `unsigned int` that is 32-bit wide, the reading of the standard says that the behaviour is undefined, i.e.

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Thus, the answer to your question is that the C standard doesn't state the behaviour in this case, and the behaviour you see is the one exhibited by your compiler and C library implementation, and is not portable; on other platforms the possible behaviours might include:

> ignoring the situation completely with **unpredictable results**, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to **terminating** a translation or **execution** (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).